# Maximizing Selenium Window without a Monitor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, graphics, webdriver, selenium4

Currently, I'm running `Selenium v4` locally on a normal PC with a graphics card and monitor. However, in production, I plan on running Selenium on a server that does not have a monitor.

When I call: `driver.maximize()` it maximizes the browser the the same height as the monitor/display. What behavior can I expect in production when the server does not have a display/monitor? How big will it maximize the window?

---

### Update

I know you could [run Selenium in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329087) but this is not my question. My question is how does Selenium/WebDriver maximize the size of the browser in this case, when it normally uses the size of the monitor/display to do so? What reference point is it using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**Resizing and positioning windows**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#resizing-and-positioning-windows) section of the ***WebDriver*** specification:

> To maximize the window, given an operating system level window with an
> associated top-level browsing context, run the implementation-specific
> steps to transition the operating system level window into the
> maximized window state. If the window manager supports window resizing
> but does not have a concept of window maximization, the window
> dimensions must be increased to the maximum available size permitted
> by the window manager for the current screen. Return when the window
> has completed the transition, or within an implementation-defined
> timeout.

In short, executing Selenium based tests on a server that does not have a monitor using `driver.maximize()`, the command invokes the window manager-specific **maximize** operation, if any, on the window containing the current top-level browsing context. This typically increases the window to the maximum available size without going full-screen.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted and accepted! Re: _the command invokes the window manager-specific maximize operation, if any, on the window containing the current top-level browsing context_ I guess this means that I would need to delve into the documentation of the OS I'm using to know how WebDriver will execute this function? For example, I plan on using CentoOS so I would need to check the docs to see how the window manager executes the maximize operation?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [get_window_size](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_window_size) to get the size of the maximized window in headless mode.

Comment: Thanks. But this is a workaround; it doesn't address the fundamental question: how does selenium determine the size when calling maximize()..